# Creating and adding row for each loop

Tags: python-3.x

Doing my first class in python so don't judge the code ;P
My problem is that I want to create a new row for each loop in my list:

```
analyserad_data = []
for i in range(2,6,1):
    analyserad_data.append(mean_value(([int(row[i]) for row in trafik_data])))
    analyserad_data.append(max_value(([int(row[i]) for row in trafik_data])))
    analyserad_data.append(min_value(([int(row[i]) for row in trafik_data])))

print(analyserad_data)
```

Gives:

```
[11645.96, 17931, 8736, 2.82, 4, 2, 8.36, 12, 7, 23.46, 29, 19]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[[11645.96, 17931, 8736],
[2.82, 4, 2],
[8.36, 12, 7],
[23.46, 29, 19]]
```

Do you guys have any suggestions for how to solve this?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried? Technically speaking it looks like you want to create a new `list` for each `iteration` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new list containing the data and append that list to your main list.

```
analyserad_data = []
for i in range(2,6,1):
    int_list = [int(row[i]) for row in trafik_data]
    temp_list = [mean_value(int_list), max_value(int_list), min_value(int_list)]
    analyserad_data.append(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a nested list by making the appended value a list:

```
for i in range(2,6,1):
    for row in trafik_data:
        analyserad_data.append(mean_value(int(row[i])), max_value(int(row[i])), min_value(int(row[i])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append new list at the beginning and then append each item to this list:

```
analyserad_data = []
for i in range(2,6,1):
    analyserad_data.append([])
    analyserad_data[-1].append(mean_value(([int(row[i]) for row in trafik_data])))
    analyserad_data[-1].append(max_value(([int(row[i]) for row in trafik_data])))
    analyserad_data[-1].append(min_value(([int(row[i]) for row in trafik_data])))

print(analyserad_data)
```